# Does IList<> guarantee order of added items in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I am using `Seed()` method of `Configuration.cs` class for filling data in database when using Update-Database command.

Among other things I am creating list of EventCategory objects like this:

```
private IList<EventCategory> CreateEventCategoriesTestDefinition()
{
    eventCategories = new List<EventCategory>();

    var eventCategoryRecruitment = new EventCategory("Recruitment");
    eventCategories.Add(eventCategoryRecruitment);

    var eventCategoryInternship = new EventCategory("Internship");
    eventCategories.Add(eventCategoryInternship);

    var eventCategoryTrainingPrograms = new EventCategory("Training Programs");
    eventCategoryTrainingPrograms.Events
        .Add(new Event("Managerial Training Program 2012-2014", eventCategoryTrainingPrograms));
    eventCategories.Add(eventCategoryTrainingPrograms);

    var eventCategoryEmployee = new EventCategory("Employee & Team Potential");
    eventCategories.Add(eventCategoryEmployee);

    return eventCategories;
}
```

Adding element by element. eventCategory is just a private property:

```
private IList<EventCategory> eventCategories;
```

From `Seed()` method I am calling `CreateEventCategoriesTestDefinition()`
Almost everything is good but when I go to database to check data I have noticed that data in EventCategory table doesn't have correct order:

[image]

As you can see it on a picture `Internship`and `Training Programs` switched positions comparing to order of adding in`CreateEventCategoriesTestDefinition()` method.

Does anybody knows what is happening here? Why order of adding is not preserved? I know it should be perserved in `List<>`, but is not the same for `IList<>`?
Or this is maybe has something to do with `EntityFramework`?

Comment: EF does not guarantee the order of inserts when saving changes. It'll build the queries from the object graphs as it sees fit. As for `IList<>`, that's just an interface: the implementation is the one which would maintain or not the order... the interface doesn't do anything

Comment: List<> (implementation) guarantees the order of the items. I think the problem is related to EF.

Comment: The list guarantees ordering but the database not because a table has no implicit order. You need to apply an `ORDER BY` on your `SELECT` statement. If you need to persist the insertion order you have to store it in  columns like `CreatedAt datetime` or `Position int`. Then use those for the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Just make Id column not autoincrement and provide values yourself (1 for Recruitment and so on).

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying upon the database for your sorting order then either.

1. Turn auto-id incrementation off and specify your own ID

   EventCategory(int id, string name)
2. If you have to use database identity then instead try using a sort order (int) column for your objects

   EventCategory(string name, int sortOrder)

Either way, you cannot guarantee that you'll get a sorted List persisted to the database. I cant say for certain your use case here, but you shouldn't reply on SQL to sort your objects for you, but when querying the database use linq to order them before binding to a view.

e.g.

```
var mySortedCategories = dbContext.EventCategories.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```